# Does the word "pirate" use the /aɪɚ/ phoneme, or the /aɪɹ/ phoneme?

Tags: vowels, rhoticity

I'm making a list of all of the graphemes can be used to make the phoneme **/aɪɚ/** in General American.

- **-ire** as in *fire, wire, desire, sapphire*, etc.
- **-yre** as in *lyre, pyre, tyre*, etc.

I have questions about a grapheme that is close, but I think doesn't quite map onto the **/aɪɚ/** phoneme:

1. I don't think the word "pirate" is pronounced with the final "ɚ" sound in "aɪɚ".  Wiktionary gives the pronunciation for *pirate* as /ˈpaɪ̯(ə)ɹət/.  Is **/aɪ̯(ə)ɹ/** the same thing as **/aɪɹ/**, similar to how "ir" is used in *spiral* (/ˈspaɪɹəl/) and *virus* (/ˈvaɪɹəs/)? If they are indeed the same, then does the "-ir" grapheme in *pirate* map onto **/aɪɹ/**, similar to the "-ir" grapheme in *virus*?
2. Just want to confirm that the **/aɪɚ/** phoneme from "fire" is separate from the **/aɪɹ/** phoneme from "virus"?

Comment: I don't pronounce *pirate* with an /aɪɚ/; the vowel is different from the one in *firearms*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/firearm) distinguishes these pronuncations; *firearm* is \ˈfī(-ə)r-ˌärm\, while *pirate* is \ ˈpī-rət\.

Comment: There is no way you could (validly) identify which version is "General American".  Even a single person is apt to use several different pronunciations.  And if you want an "official" pronunciation you'll have to wait til [Talk Like a Pirate Day](https://nationaldaycalendar.com/international-talk-like-a-pirate-day-september-19/).

Comment: Hot Licks - Just emphasizing that I'm looking for an American pronunciation, not a British one... as I understand it, the British would use a non-rhotic pronunciation for fire/pyre (ending with "/aɪə/")..

Comment: It might depend on whether you're pronouncing it like the prototypical pirate (-ire) or an English gentleman (-yre).

Comment: West Country British (and "pirate English") is certainly rhotic.

Comment: Watch out for marauding pirates seeking pyrite.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  And American English is often new-rhotic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Longman Pronunciation dictionary* gives **/paɪᵊr ət/** (also acceptable, /ɪt/), in both BrE and Gen Am. The word has two syllables and superscript schwa stands for the pronunciation of schwa, which is not recommended; this symbol means that occasionally the sound schwa is inserted and then the word contains three syllables: /paɪ ər ət/.

*LPD, 2000* p. 757

> Likely syllabic consonants are shown in LPD with the symbol ᵊ, thus **suddenly** 'sʌd ᵊn li. LPD's regular principle is that a raised symbol indicates a sound whose inclusion LPD does not recommend (see OPTIONAL SOUNDS). Hence  this notation implies that LPD prefers bare n in the second syllable. Since there is no proper vowel in this syllable, the n must be syllabic. (Thus it is possible, though not usual, to say 'sʌd ən li rather than 'sʌd n li.

Fire

BrE: 'fa*ɪ*‿ə  (The italic ɪ shows that the sound ɪ may be absent; one or two syllables; 'fa ə, 'faə)
GenAm: faɪ‿ᵊr  (Schwa is replaced by syllabic r, but ɪ is always retained.)

Comment: Superscript schwa + another consonant (usually /l m n r/) means that the following consonant is syllabic.

Comment: Does the IPA symbol /paɪᵊr ət/ mean the vowel in the first syllable of *pirate* is pronounced like *pie* or like *pyre*? This is the question the OP is asking, and if *fire* is represented as /faɪ‿ᵊr/ the notation /paɪᵊr ət/ seems truly ambiguous.

Comment: @PeterShor No, it is not ambiguous: it is like "pie", normally ('paɪr ət) ; the ending type that induces a solid schwa in BrE and a syllabic r in Gen Am is -ire, -yre (tire ta_ɪ_‿ə||a_ɪ_‿ᵊr ;  notice that there is no separation in /paɪᵊr ət/ whereas in /ta_ɪ_‿ə||aɪ‿ᵊr/ there is one, indicated by the ligature, which means that there is the option of one or two syllables according to the schemes "/ta_ɪ_ ə||taɪ  ᵊr/ " and /taɪ(ə)||aɪr/ . Where i is followed by r the strong pronunciation is aɪ(ə).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Right, but in LPD, only if  compulsory (separation and no ligature, swivel /swɪv ᵊl/); notice reɪᵊl, reɪᵊl ɪŋ (railing (trains)), but reɪl ɪŋ (fence). When there is no separation it is rather an indication of unusual syllabifying of the given consonant.